# A better strip_tags alternative?

Tags: php

I have a website with CKEditor, To prevent XSS attacks I used strip_tags but the problem is that it also breaks the WYISWYG editor (CKEditor).

Like, stackoverflow is secure to XSS attacks BUT it does not block any tags.

How can I acomplish the same effect?

I want users to be able to share code

Comment: Use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

Comment: [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)? Converts symbols like `<` and `>` to values like `&gt;`

Comment: No, *don't* use HTML purifier. Just properly escape your output.

Comment: Why not just wrap <code> tags around your code?

Comment: `</code> function do_evil_stuff() { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php's `strip_tags` supports allowed tags example direct from php docs site:

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');


//output :
//Test paragraph. Other text
//<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
```

maybe this can help

Comment: Then you display them as HTML anyway. He wants users to share code, not 'run' code.